# Adding a rotated rectangle to a path without allocating memory

Tags: java, android, memory, matrix, 2d

If I try to allocate any memory during onDraw in my View-derived class in my Android app, Eclipse/lint gives me warnings that I shouldn't be allocating memory during the execution of onDraw. so I'm trying to think of the best way to append a rotated rectangle to a path that may get used to define clipping bounds. I'm also going to want to figure out how to add a rotated ellipse to such a path.

I have considered using Matrix.mapPoints with the 4 corners of the rectangle (using a pre-allocated matrix), but I don't currently have a pre-allocated array of floats to use with that, and I'm not sure I want to do that if there's another way. Should I use Math.atan2 to get polar coordinates, offset the result, and then use sin and cos to calculate new coordinates, or is that going to have a lot more overhead than the matrix multiplication?

Are there other ways of adding rotated rectangles and ellipses to clipping boundaries that I should consider?

**Edit:** I'm also not clear if calling other functions that have local variables would be considered memory allocation. If I create a function like this:

```
private void drawOperation(Operation op, Canvas canvas) {
    float coords[] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
    ....
}
```

Does that array get created on the heap or the stack? Does it still constitute something that should be avoided during onDraw?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am considering code like this, where mMatrix, mRotationPath, mPoint and mPath are pre-allocated objects:

```
mMatrix.setRotate(angle, mPoint.x, mPoint.y);
mRotationPath.rewind();
mRotationPath.addRect(mRect, Path.Direction.CW);
mPath.addPath(mRotationPath, mMatrix);
```